# PDO is not working with CakePHP installation

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo, mamp

I am configuring a cakePHP application, but the app doesn't seems to connect successfully to DB, I got the following error:

```
Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

I renamed the `database.php.default` to `database.php` and here is the code:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost:8889',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'cakephpdb',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Actually, I know CakePHP use PDO driver to connect to DB, so I tried to run a separate file just to test whether the PDO is true of false:

```
<?php

var_dump( extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') );

?>
```

And it's false:

```
bool(false)
```

I tried to enable PDO in `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Restarted MAMP, but still the same error for cakePHP app. Am I missing something? how do you make sure PDO is enabled in your cases? Thanx in advance.

***EDIT:***

When running phpinfo(), the PDO_MySQL is not enabled:
[image]

The php.ini path is the follwoing, according to phpinfo() output:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf
```

[image]

So I tried to edit the `php.ini` file at that path and here is the relevant settings:

```
    extension=imap.so
    extension=yaz.so
    extension=mcrypt.so
    extension=gettext.so
    extension=pgsql.so
    extension=pdo_pgsql.so
    extension=pdo_mysql.so

pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Also, I tried to test the DB connection in a php script:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 'localhost', 'root');
    echo '<br /> success';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";


    die();
}
```

And I gto always the following error:

```
Error !: could not find driver
```

So the `PDO_Mysql` driver is not loaded, and that's clear from the phpinfo() output. Out to fix that?

Comment: There are a LOT of questions/answers about CakePHP, MySQL, PDO...etc.  Have you already read through them?

Comment: First make sure that Pdo is really enabled now - check the output of phpinfo() in your browser. Next write a simple script using PDO and your database settings (you can get copy/paste code from the manual). Does it still not work with CakePHP once you have made sure that your settings are working and PDO is installed correctly?

Comment: Hi, thanx for replying, I edited my post for further details about my actual configuration settings on `php.ini` file. I tried all suggestions on similar threads on stackoverflow but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the changes? Have you verified that the `pdo_mysql.so` is actually present? Also, check the various log files, it's possible that `pdo_mysql.so` is *present*, but not compiled for your architecture (e.g. Not compiled for 64-bit). When restarting Apache, it's best to 'stop' it, then check that all Apache (httpd) processes are really stopped (sometimes a process may keep running) and *then* start it again

Comment: Yes, `pdo_mysql.so` file is present in `bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525` path. Also, I restarted MAMP, I even rebooted my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed whether you're updating the correct php.ini? For XAMPP, there is a php.ini for the console, and another for the webserver. You might be updating the incorrect one.